# Is every word of the Vedas authoritative according to Samkhya school?

Tags: vedas

Vedas are said to be eternal and authorless so are vedas fully authoritative(every single word) according to Samkhya school ?

Comment: Many similar questions were already posted in the past. You may want to search before posting any new question.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto can you give those questions

Comment: Both ancient and modern scholars and pundits accept that the Sankhya philosophy was astika. There are no modern followers of this ancient philosophy. You may like to read the chapter on the Sankhya philosophy in Chapter 9 here - https://archive.org/details/IndianPhilosophyACriticalSurvey